# Reading file and adding to object?

Tags: java, io, linked-list

So what I want to do is to read from a file and then use what it read and place it in objects(the first line in the file says how many students are in said file, then it goes through students. That first amount is also the amount of objects i want to create). I have tried using a LinkedList (as changes may need to be made) to store the info and hopefully use in the object but to no avail. Here is my code :

```
    public static void start() {

    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("students.dat"));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> student = new LinkedList<String>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        student.add(s.nextLine());
    }
    s.close();

    int count;
    count = Integer.parseInt((student.get(0)));

    int id = 1;

    while (count > 0) {//code in here or replacing here

        count--;
    }


}
```

Cant help but feel that i'm missing something simple... Was thinking of using for each loop or Collections. Any help or direction to go would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem with this code? (e.g. an error or it does not achieve the desired result?)

Comment: @Ivan Not exactly i'm looking for help on how to proceed; I need to store students details so I was thinking of using a LinkedList<String>, I need to able to search for elements in the List (Like a student number) and retrieve information about the student (like name and subjects that student takes). Thanks for trying to help out.